Vscode extension for cakephp import?
For instance I have the following statement,
TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Users')->find()
Intelephense is showing, Undefined type 'App\Controller\Api\TableRegistry'.intelephense(P1009)
Quick fix under TableRegistry is not showing any suggestion for the correct Cake import, Cake\ORM\TableRegistry in this case.
Is there any extension that can make VSCode provide the correct suggestion or even auto add the necessary import statement?

You can use PHP Intelephense extension
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client

I do have that. Some how it's not suggesting in quick fix.

Maybe it is conflicting with another extension.
